# how to get all the items of list c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In a list i have 4 rows and I am try to get all the rows of the list but it is giving only one row, how to get all the rows of the list.

I have tried below code

```
public async Task<ResponseUserModel> get()
    {
        List<ResponseUserModel> responseUsers = new List<ResponseUserModel>();
        using (nae2sasqld0003Entities context = new nae2sasqld0003Entities())
        {
            var listt =  context.Producers.Select(all => all).ToList();

            foreach (var item in listt)
            {
                responseUsers.Add(new ResponseUserModel
                {
                    ProducerName = item.ProducerName,
                    ResidentState = item.ResidentState,
                    ResidentCity = item.ResidentCity,
                    ProducerStatus = item.ProducerStatus,
                    ProducerCode = item.ProducerCode,
                    MasterCode = item.MasterCode,
                    NationalCode = item.NationalCode,
                    LegacyChubbCodes = item.LegacyChubbCodes,
                    LegacyPMSCode = item.LegacyPMSCode,
                    ProducingBranchCode = item.ProducingBranchCode,
                    CategoryCode = item.CategoryCode
                });
            }
            return responseUsers;
        }
    }
```

please let me know where i to fix the issue

Comment: From a quick glance it seems that the `responseUserModel`is always null. Even if it wasn't null, I think it should be an IList<ResponseUserModel> instead of one ResponseUserModel.

Comment: why is negative value on question

Answer (score 2):

Use list to return all:

```
List<ResponseUserModel> responseUsers = new List<ResponseUserModel>();
```

then

```
foreach (var item in listt)
{
       responseUsers.Add(new ResponseUserModel
       {
           ProducerName = item.ProducerName,
           ResidentState = item.ResidentState,
           ResidentCity = item.ResidentCity,
           ProducerStatus = item.ProducerStatus,
           ProducerCode = item.ProducerCode,
           MasterCode = item.MasterCode,
           NationalCode = item.NationalCode,
           LegacyChubbCodes = item.LegacyChubbCodes,
           LegacyPMSCode = item.LegacyPMSCode,                  
           ProducingBranchCode = item.ProducingBranchCode,
           CategoryCode = item.CategoryCode
       });
}
return responseUsers;
```

**Note**: change return type of the method to `IList<ResponseUserModel>`

or in this way

```
using (var context = new nae2sasqld0003Entities())
{
    return context.Producers.Select(item => 
        new ResponseUserModel
           {
               ProducerName = item.ProducerName,
               ResidentState = item.ResidentState,
               ResidentCity = item.ResidentCity,
               ProducerStatus = item.ProducerStatus,
               ProducerCode = item.ProducerCode,
               MasterCode = item.MasterCode,
               NationalCode = item.NationalCode,
               LegacyChubbCodes = item.LegacyChubbCodes,
               LegacyPMSCode = item.LegacyPMSCode,                  
               ProducingBranchCode = item.ProducingBranchCode,
               CategoryCode = item.CategoryCode
           }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer on  responseuser i am getting error - can not convert generic list to model. how to solve this

Comment: Where? What code do use use? You need to change return type of the method to `List<ResponseUserModel>`

Comment: actually i am using web api model first approach. producers is coming from db and  ResponseUserModel is local class

Comment: Ok, I see. As I said before (and added to the answer) if you want list then you need to change return type of the method to List<ResponseUserModel>

Comment: yes, i have changed that now its working fine thanks.